# Merge folders and keep different file versions

Tags: windows, robocopy, file-history

Is it possible to merge multiple folder and keep all files in e.g. Windows 10. I was thinking about something somehow similiar to the Windows File History.

For example, i have 2 folders (`c:\folder`, `d:\folder`) with 3 files each (`file1.txt`, `file2.jpg`, `file3.doc`). However, `file2.jpg` in `c:\folder` is older (13.03.2016 12:00) than `file2.jpg` in `d:\folder` (14.03.2016 06:00).

I would like to merge both folders into one folder but keep both versions of `file2.jpg`. The older file should either be moved to a subfolder (`d:\folder\old`) and/or renamed to `file2.jpg_201603131200`.

Is there a program for this? Can this be done with robocopy? Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hey David. Thanks for your comment. It was not in my intention to receive a complete script. I asked if there is a program that can do this, and if for example robocopy would be the right choice. For further ideas i am grateful. Before asking this question I did a extended search on this topic. I tried robocopy (+richcopy) and winmerge. None of them fitted my needs directly (I believe). Then i looked up which stackexchange site would be the right one to ask this general question. I believe there should be a solution to this problem already, don't you think so?

Comment: Unlikely to be a ready made solution. I think a script is required.